# android: nothing shows up in autocomplete result

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-filterable

I have implemented `Filterable` for my `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
public class IdiomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    Context context;
    List<Idiom> idioms;

    public IdiomAdapter(Context context, List<Idiom> idioms){
        this.context = context;
        this.idioms = idioms;
        originaList = new ArrayList<Idiom>(idioms);
        filter = new IdiomFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (idioms != null) {
            return idioms.size();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return idioms.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return idioms.get(arg0).getId();
    }



    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    private IdiomFilter filter;
    ArrayList<Idiom> originaList;

    public class IdiomFilter extends Filter {

        public IdiomFilter(){

        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Idiom> result = new ArrayList<Idiom>();
            if (originaList == null) {
                originaList = (ArrayList<Idiom>) idioms;
            }

            if (constraint !=null) {
                if (originaList !=null && originaList.size() > 0) {
                    for (Idiom idiom : originaList) {
                        if (idiom.getVerb().contains(constraint))
                            result.add(idiom);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = result;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            idioms = (ArrayList<Idiom>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;

        // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
        // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

And using it in my activity:

```
IdiomAdapter adapter = new IdiomAdapter(MainActivity.this, idioms);
AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
txtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
```

when I type keyword in `AutoCompleteTextView`, seems that work but nothing shows up in result:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Check your array list is having value or not????

Comment: yes, values are populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to `setThreshold(1)` of `AutoCompleteTextView`.
add this line:

```
txtSearch.setThreshold(1);
```

adapter using this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataSearchModel> {
    private ArrayList<DataSearchModel> items;
    private ArrayList<DataSearchModel> itemsAll;
    private ArrayList<DataSearchModel> suggestions;
    private int viewResourceId;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DataSearchAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId,
            ArrayList<DataSearchModel> items) {
        super(context, viewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.itemsAll = (ArrayList<DataSearchModel>) items.clone();
        this.suggestions = new ArrayList<DataSearchModel>();
        this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(viewResourceId, null);
        }
        DataSearchModel _data = items.get(position);
        if (_data != null) {
              TextView dataLabel = (TextView)  v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            if (dataLabel != null) {
                dataLabel.setText(_data.getDataName());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return nameFilter;
    }

    Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = ((DataSearchModel) (resultValue)).getDataName();
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (DataSearchModel _data : itemsAll) {
                    if (_data.getDataName().toLowerCase()
                            .startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(_data);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<DataSearchModel> filteredList = (ArrayList<DataSearchModel>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (DataSearchModel c : filteredList) {
                    add(c);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: @SirwanAfifi change your adapter using the adapter code that i post.